# How can I cast video from my PC to chrome-cast via hotel WiFi

Tags: wireless-networking, chromecast

I am staying in a hotel long term. There is wifi available, but only through a "sign-in" page, so chromecast cannot connect to the wifi. I can share the internet connection through my win10 laptop, using the "mobile hotspot" feature. But my laptop and chromecast are not on the same wifi network.

How can view videos from my laptop on the chromecast connected TV?

I also have an IOS and an Android phone available if that helps. I have usb memory sticks. I have mini-dp and hdmi cables but not a mini-dp-to-hdmi adapter (laptop has mini dp-out only)

Answer (score 0):

Just make WiFi AP on the Android phone and connect both the chromecast and your laptop to it.

Comment: This answer is fine... Create a wirelessly network on the Android. From there join both. It may work however Chromecast devices can be picky about types of WiFi.